# Edittext Functionality

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 4 edittext, what i want is when i enter any digit on first edittext, It should move to second edittext, Similarly with second and third edit text, but when cursor reaches to forth edittext, if code is wrong then if I delete forth edittext value ,it should come backward till to first edittext.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please provide what you have tried and where you have failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher
    {
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttext1);
        editText1.addTextChangedListener(this);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttext2);
       editText2.addTextChangedListener(this);

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        if (s.toString().length() == 1)
       {
          editText2.requestFocus();
       }
  }
```

Try this code check out...

Comment: this I applied for forwarding,to come backward I applied keylistener,but together both are not working

Comment: i didn't get you what you exactly want..!

Comment: See,there is four edittext ,when first edittext has filled then cursor is moving  to next  edittext,when second edittext has filled then cursor is moving to third ,third has filled then cursor will be on forth,when forth edittext has filled then it is checking that OTP is correct or not.but when I am deleting forth edittext value then cursor is not comming back on third,So I posted the code what I have done,You can see